# Minor tweak to this javascript function?

Tags: javascript

I have a script that shows/hides used via onClick. I can get it to show/hide just fine, but I can't get it to show/'hide everything else'. So what I get is a bunch of open containers when I really want just the one.

Javascript:

```
<script>
    function showfields(fields){
        if(document.getElementById(fields).style.display=='none'){
            document.getElementById(fields).style.display='block';
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById(fields).style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="hidden" class="steps" style="display: block;">
    <div class="section" style="margin-right: 10px;">
        <h2>Something</h2>
    </div>
    <button class="continue dropdown" id="showLink" onClick="showfields('hidden2');return false;" href="#">Continue</button>
</div>
<div id="hidden2" class="steps" style="display: block;">
    <div class="section" style="margin-right: 10px;">
        <h2>Something2</h2>
    </div>
    <button class="continue dropdown" id="showLink" onClick="showfields('hidden3');return false;" href="#">Continue</button>
</div>
<div id="hidden3" class="steps" style="display: block;">
    <div class="section" style="margin-right: 10px;">
        <h2>Something3</h2>
    </div>
    <button class="continue dropdown" id="showLink" onClick="showfields('hidden3');return false;" href="#">Continue</button>
</div>
<div id="hidden4" class="steps" style="display: block;">
    <div class="section" style="margin-right: 10px;">
        <h2>Something4</h2>
    </div>
    <button class="continue dropdown" id="showLink" onClick="showfields('hidden4');return false;" href="#">Continue</button>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: How are you passing/constructing `fields` variable ?

Comment: Removed jQuery tag - there is no jquery in this question

Comment: What is the question? what is **Exactly** the question?

Comment: @Tom I think the OP was using that tag to say "jQuery answers are acceptable", but it probably would have been better just to say that instead (or at least in addition to the tag).

Comment: I hadn't thought of that.  Probably should also have it in the question to avoid confusion.  If RKS wants it that way, we can change it back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you've tagged this with jQuery I assume that is an option:

```
function showfields(fields){
  $('.steps').hide()
  $('#' + fields).show();
}
```

Comment: What are you talking about? He wants to hide all the others and show the one that was clicked on which is exactly what my function will do.

Comment: oh sorry i didn't see $('.steps').hide() but now i can't remove downvote until you edit this

Comment: I did tag with jQuery because I am already using jQuery so that was an option. I guess I could have stated that but I thought it would be assumed (which it was, apparently.) This works, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**
Is this what you're trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/Rykus0/67cjt/2/
(without jQuery)

(ps - this can be done better)

---

Your question is not very clear, but I'm guessing that you want the page to start with the everything but the first div hidden.

In that case, what you have is fine, just set `style="display:none;"` on the elements you don't want to show at first (you can also use a class).

Also, I believe you should change the `onclick` call on hidden3 to be `showfields('hidden4')` and remove the onclick event from hidden4

Comment: This is a valid solution to this question and it works perfectly. The only reason it isn't the answer is that my code above is stripped down for easier reading but there are elements inbetween the hidden divs so that renders your nextElementSibling not exactly what I need. Also, sorry my question wasn't clear.

Comment: You still get an upvote since you have provided a solution exactly as the code above describes.

Comment: Fair enough.  I'm glad you found the help you needed!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Porco,

Another option would be using a class as a flag, for example

```
function showFields(fields){
     $(fields).each(function(){
         if($(this).hasClass('visible'){
              $(this).hide();
         }
         else {
              $(this).show();
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using jquery .This piece of javascript may help you

```
  <script>
        function showfields(fields){
          for(var i=0;i<document.body.getElementsByTagName("*").length;i++)
          { if(document.body.getElementsByTagName("*")[i].id==field)
            {
            document.body.getElementsByTagName("*")[i].style.display='block';
            }
            else{
                 document.body.getElementsByTagName("*")[i].style.display='block';

            }
        }
    </script>
```